# Complete button not showing up in SurveyJS

Tags: surveyjs

Hi I have configured SurveyJS latest version and after implementing I see that out of box "Complete" button is not showing up on the last page. Looks like I am missing some setting or configuration. Can someone suggest what needs to be done. I have implemented Survey JS using Knockout js.

Expecting the out of the box "Complete" button to be shown on the survey.